# how to create operator[] for set?

Tags: c++, set

i have this class in c++ :

```
class Company{
    string PhoneNumber;
    std::set<ER*> Rooms;
public:
    // some other functions
}
```

now i want to write operator `=` for this class and i am having a problem to go through the set

this is what i got so far :

```
Company& Company::operator=(const Company& company){
    if(this==&company){
        return *this;
    }
    int numRooms=Rooms.size();
        for(int i=0;i<numRooms;i++){
            delete Rooms[i];
        }
     int numCompanyRooms=company.Rooms.size();
       for(int i=0;i<numCompanyRooms;i++){
        Rooms[i]= new ER(*company.Rooms[i]); // i get error no match operator [] !
                }
       Rooms=company.Rooms;
       return *this;
}
```

any help of what i am doing wrong here !?

Comment: The non existent  `operator[]` aside, you need to explain your code to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Are you sure `std::set` has overloaded `operator[]` ?

Comment: Unrelated, but I sure hope the sizes of both sets are the same ...

Comment: If your set didn't contain pointers you wouldn't need an `operator=` at all. Why does it contain pointers?

Comment: Stop using a set of raw pointers... all your problems will go away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access elements in a `set` by index.You will have to iterate over the entire `set`.
To empty the existing set, you need to explicitly `delete` elements and then call `clear`.Then to copy `Rooms` from `company`, you will have to iterate `Company.Rooms`.Also you will have to find out how are going to make copies of `ER` as it depends on definition of `ER`.

```
Company& Company::operator=(const Company& company)
{
    if(this==&company)
        return *this;
    for(auto itr = Rooms.begin(); itr!=Rooms.end(); itr++)
    {
       ER* deleteMe = *itr;
       delete deleteMe;
    }
    Rooms.clear();//Empty the set.Note that clear() does not delete so we explicitly called it before.
    for(auto itr = company.Romms.begin(); itr!=company.Rooms.end(); itr++)
    {
       ER* newER = new ER();
       //copy *itr into newER in proper way.This depends on 
       //definition of ER.Maybe you can check if there assignment operator
       //for ER as well and utilize it.
       Rooms.insert(newER);
    }
    return *this;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Set` doesn't take care of index of element in it, it is only concerned if element is in the set or not. So `Rooms[i]` doesn't exist, and you can't overload operator `[]` for set.